# sfml close window after left click if the the coordinates of the page were less than 200 and 200, the window would close

Tags: c++, sfml

hi i'm trying to write code on sfml that After the left click on the window, if the coordinates of the page were less than 200 and 200, the window would close
but i have some problems on the second part   so how can i add the secound part imean if the coordinates of the page were less than 200,200 the window would close

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
{
    if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Right)
    {
                window.close();//saber bahramifar
        }
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are your "problems on the second part" ?

Comment: if the window less than 200 , 200 close with left click  // so how can i add this with "if"

Comment: Clarifications to questions should be in the body of the question. [edit] it and put details like this in there.